# Vue.js styling with javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am using ChartJs and I want to customize the legend field. I can get the color code without any problem.
I am trying to format it like we do in JavaScript but the color is not showing up.

```
spanBox.style.backgroundColor = bgColor;
```

Comment: please post a more complete code snippet that includes the template code of the element you're trying to manipulate and other surrounding code to provide better context for where and how you're using the 1 line of code you've provided so far.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're after, but you could do something like this:

```
<script setup>
const bgColor = '#ff00ff'; // Replace with a computed, a function return a value, etc.
</script>

<template>
<div :style="{ backgroundColor: bgColor }"></div>
</template>
```

Comment: Thank you for your support. But this is not possible as I am rendering the div with javascript.